# How to get info/details from p12 type keystore file

Tags: openssl, keystore, asn.1, pkcs#12

I am trying to get p12 type details as below,

`openssl pkcs12 -info -in keystore.p12`

But, its giving error

```
2512:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1180:
2512:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:365:Type=PKCS12
```

Any idea, please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get your keystore.p12 file?  [This post](https://www.ssl247.com/kb/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting/apache/errors-asn1-encoding-routine-apache) seems to indicate that there's an error in the format of the file, and has some suggestions on how to address it.

Specifically, it indicates to check and make sure there are no [leading or trailing] spaces in the file.

Are you sure its properly formatted?

Comment: Thanks for your response, It was .p12 generation issue. I resolved it. I used open ssl to create .p12 file. command as below `openssl pkcs12 -export -out Keystore.p12 -in ServerCert.pem -inkey ServerKey.pem`